# How to read data file with coordinates in GLPK

Tags: ampl, glpk, mathprog

I this [example](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) is used

```
# random locations for the cities
param cx{i in N} := Uniform01();
param cy{i in N} := Uniform01();
```

for generate random locations for the cities

How to read data file with coordinates in GLPK and how format?

```
1 2 3 4
1,2,3,4
(1,2),(3,4)
{1,2},{3,4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glpk uses GNU MathProg, a subset of [AMPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMPL), so given the following parameter and set declarations:

```
set N := 1..2;
param cx{i in N};
param cy{i in N};
```

you can read the data as follows

```
data;
param:
  cx cy :=
1  1  2
2  3  4;
```

Note that in this case parameters `cx` and `cy` shouldn't be defined in the model, so you should either remove the `:= Uniform01()` part or change it to `default Uniform01()`.

Comment: Error: N needs no data
Context: ...> filename ; } printf '...' >> filename ; data ; param : N :

Comment: My code snippet: param n := 2;

# set of cities
set N := {1..n};

Comment: @RegisdaSilva I've updated the answer for the case of N defined in the model.

Comment: Thank yout for solution.